# Jenkins Git change submodule path

Tags: git, jenkins, git-submodules

Is there a way to change the submodule path to pull from a different repository during build time?

Comment: Are you talking about changing the submodule repo URL? If so, see answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Submodule URLs are set in the `.gitmodules` file in your repo, so you just need to modify the URL within that file.

[`git-config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) accepts a `-f` argument indicating the config file, which you can use to specify the `.gitmodules` file instead of the normal `.git/config` or `~/.gitconfig` files which are normally used. Using this option, you could modify the submodule URL with the following:

```
git config -f .gitmodules submodule.<submodule name>.url <new URL>
```

Or, you could manually modify the submodule's URL in the `.gitmodules` file to the changed path. A shell script phase prior to your build phase in Jenkins could accomplish modifying that file, and if necessary you could `git checkout -- .` afterward to restore the original URL.

Either way, you'll want to run `git submodule sync` afterward to reflect the change in the containing repo.